# Connection and overlap between Analytic and Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was browsing on Part III guide to courses and found out that the course named Algebraic Number Theory covers topics that I would not expect them to be covered in an algebraic course. I am talking about things like ζ-functions, analytic class number formula and L-functions that all sound quite "analytic". Therefore the question comes to my mind about how analytic number theory and algebraic number theory connect, their overlap and how one should approach studying these topics.

Comment: Algebraic number theory is the study of the algebraic numbers, not the algebraic study of numbers. I remember when I did part III, just before the chapter proving the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function, the lecturer made clear that you can't expect to study algebraic number theory without doing at least some analysis!

Comment: @Mathmo123 so analytic number theory is the study of the analytic numbers? If you look at the Wikipedia pages in other languages, quite often algebraic number theory and analytic number theory are called algebraic theory of numbers and analytic theory of numbers.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "not just" the algebraic study of numbers. But in any case, the part III algebraic number theory course is very much a course about the algebraic numbers, from all perspectives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many zeta and $L$-functions are defined using algebraic input, such as zeta-functions of number fields, $L$-functions of Galois representations (of suitable types), and Hasse-Weil zeta-functions of algebraic varieties.

The analytic class number formula, especially for quadratic fields, is a fantastic way of computing class numbers, which is of interest in algebraic number theory. For example, it reveals that the equation $1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9-1/11+\cdots = \pi/4$ implies $\mathbf Z[i]$ is a PID. The analytic class number formula goes back to Dedekind's work on algebraic number theory.

The Chebotarev density theorem is an analytic result about Frobenius conjugacy classes of prime ideals in a Galois group, so its very meaning can't be understood well without algebraic number theory.

The original proofs of class field theory were based in crucial places on complex analysis.

Have you looked at many algebraic number theory books? With high probability you'll find part of such a book discusses analytic techniques for getting information of interest in number fields.

Frohlich and Taylor's book *Algebraic Number Theory* has a chapter titled "$L$-functions".

Lang's book *Algebraic Number Theory* has chapters on zeta-functions and $L$-series and its third part is called “Analytic Theory”.

Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* has a chapter called "Zeta-functions and $L$-series"

Swinnerton-Dyer's *A Brief Guide to Algebraic Number Theory* has a chapter called "Analytic methods".

Comment: +1, very nice answer. The analytic class number formula is one of the most beautiful in all of mathematics.